# Accessing other fields in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got the following model.

```
class FAQ(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=False)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I've also got the following ModelForm

```
class FAQForm (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('user',) 
        model = FAQ


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(FAQForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Within my model form, how can I access the the value within the user field of the FAQ model? I'd like to be able to access it under def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs): or super().

Thanks so much!

Comment: When updating an object with a `ModelForm` there will be a parameter passed in `kwargs` named `instance` that will be the instance being updated and will have all the fields available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Thanks Iain.

```
class FAQForm (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('user',) 
        model = FAQ


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(FAQForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        user = self.instance.user
```